# Why is the long-run average production cost not necessarily the same as the minimum average total cost?

Tags: microeconomics, theory-of-the-firm

As you can see from the graph, the LRATC doesn't touch the SRATC curves when they're at their minimum. Why is this so?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Denesp's comment is your full answer: it's a badly-drawn chart which fails to do its one job, that was to illustrate that the long-run cost curve consists of joining up the minima of the short-run cost curves.

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice explanation, just take a look at the source [here](http://www.economicsdiscussion.net/cost/short-run-and-long-run-average-cost-curve/25523).