# Why does LRAC not connect the minima of SRAC curves?

Tags: production-function, cost, producer-theory, cost-functions

Can anyone please provide an intuitive explanation and proper mathematical reason for non-intersection of SRAC and LRAC at the minimas of SRAC?

I am seeing conflicting [[1]](https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/14900/34330) [[2]](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/18775/why-is-the-long-run-average-production-cost-not-necessarily-the-same-as-the-mini) answers on the site regarding this. My [textbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/938666805X) (Chapter 10, page 355) too does not do a great job in explaining the graph:

[image]

Comment: @AdamBailey it looks like duplicate to me too but I am not sure to close it with mod vote outright consider voting close

Comment: @AdamBailey More like literal duplicate. I am going to shamelessly advertise my simple explanatory [example](https://economics.stackexchange.com/a/32519/1601) before voting to close though.

Comment: @Giskard What is y in your explanation? (I don't have sufficient reputation to comment)

Comment: @AdamBailey The answer linked is not intuitive or exhaustive, it just has a 
complicated use case of Cobb Douglas;  and neither does it cover why at minima of LRAC, SRAC also has its minima.

Comment: @reasonStore Output/quantity. Your textbook seems to denote it by $q$. Also Adam Bailey is linking to a different question then I am; I am linking to the one with the Cobb-Douglas answer. You can read his - perhaps - easier to comprehend answer behind [his link](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/32513/is-it-possible-that-the-minimum-point-of-a-short-run-cost-curve-does-not-touch-t).

Comment: @Giskard Understood your answer, thanks! But this question still remains: why at minima of LRAC, SRAC also has its minima?

Comment: Where is this question posted? Seems like a new question?

Comment: @Giskard I asked that in my question only.

Comment: I don't see it in the [body of your post](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/43785/why-does-lrac-not-connect-the-minima-of-srac-curves). If you want to ask a new question, post it as a new question.